# Sync Folders With PowerShell

Tags: powershell

i try this script to synchronize 2 folder

```
$Folder1Path = 'C:\test1'
$Folder2Path = 'C:\test2'
$folder1Files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path $Folder1Path
$folder2Files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path $Folder2Path
$file_Diffs = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $folder1Files -DifferenceObject $folder2Files
$file_Diffs | foreach {
$copyParams = @{'Path' = $_.InputObject.FullName}
if($_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' )
{$copyParams.Destination = $Folder2Path}
copy-Item @copyParams -force
}
```

But i have a problem when the script copy the file under test2 it does not respect the correct path :

in  folder test1 i have:
 test1\test3\test4.txt and test1\test5.txt 
in  folder test2 i have:
test2\test5.txt

when i execute my script i find in folder test2 
test2\test5.txt
test2\test4.txt
test2\test3

Comment: you should better use robocopy here

Comment: how i can use robocopy ??

Comment: if you want $folder2 to be an exact copy of $folder1 do this `robocopy.exe $folder1 $folder2 /MIR`

Comment: i try robocopy my script is like this:                $Folder1Path = 'C:\test1'
 $Folder2Path = 'C:\test2'
 robocopy $Folder1Path $Folder2Path /COPYALL /B /SEC /MIR /R:0 /W:0 /NFL /NDL /NJH /NJS

Comment: how can i define crone in powershell to make it work automatically ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting your destination for `Copy-Item` always to `'C:\test1'`. That will ignore any deeper folder structure of the source file. If you want to keep the folder structure of the source, you would need to adjust the FullName property of your file accordingly:

```
$Folder1Path = 'C:\test1'
$Folder2Path = 'C:\test2'
$folder1Files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path $Folder1Path
$folder2Files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path $Folder2Path
$file_Diffs = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $folder1Files -DifferenceObject $folder2Files
$file_Diffs | 
  foreach {
     $copyParams = @{'Path' = $_.InputObject.FullName}
     if($_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' )
     { 
         $copyParams.Destination = $_.InputObject.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($Folder1Path),$Folder2Path
     }
     copy-Item @copyParams -force
}
```